# How to get all test methods' names from an extern .class file

Tags: java

I'm trying to get testing methods' names from extern .class files.
Here is the directory tree：

- classes

  - CMD.class
- target-classes

  - CMDTest.class
  - CMDTest1.class
  - CMDTest2.class

Adding these files to working directory is not allowed.

My solution is using **URLClassloader** to load all the files from the target-classes and then using getDeclaredMethods() to get all the methods with annotation @Test. However, there are some custom exceptions defined in CMD.class which with cause exceptions as follows:

- "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: CMD$OptionException"

OptionException is defined in CMD.class.

How to solve this problem or is there any effective methods to get testing methods' names from extern .class files？

Thanks a lot!

Comment: “OptionException is defined in CMD.class.” — That’s unlikely; it *should* be defined in `CMD$OptionException.class`. Your class loader needs to be able to find that file (in fact, based on what you wrote I’d expect this file to be in the `classes` folder so, again, if I understood you correctly it should be loaded by the *default* class loader; the fact that this isn’t the case is odd).

Answer (score -1):

Codes are as follows:

```java
        URL[] urls = {new URL("file:D:\\test-classes\\"),};
        URLClassLoader myClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
        File classesDirectory = new File("D:\\Lab1\\classes\\net\\mooctest");
        File testClassesDirectory = new File("D:\\Lab1\\test-classes\\net\\mooctest");
        File[] classesList = classesDirectory.listFiles();
        File[] testClassesList = testClassesDirectory.listFiles();
        for (File file : testClassesList) {
            //net.mooctest is package name
            Class clazz = myClassLoader.loadClass("net.mooctest." + file.getName().split("\\.")[0]);
            Method[] declaredMethods = clazz.getDeclaredMethods();
            for (Method method : declaredMethods) {
                Test declaredAnnotation = method.getDeclaredAnnotation(Test.class);
                if (declaredAnnotation != null) {
                    System.out.println(method.getDeclaringClass() + " " + method.getName());
                }
            }
        }
```